# How to translate __('') strings in admin

Tags: plugins, translation

What would be the best plugin to use for translating website.

Thing is - i installed one multilingual plugin, but it does not pick up strings from templates. For example - the template has stuff lke 
`<?php _e('Search Results', 'kubrick'); ?>` 
in it - what plugin should i use to translate them in admin? So far i havent been able to find any.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to create your .POT file, here are some instructions:

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2007/08/27/localizing-a-wordpress-plugin-using-poedit/

Comment: isnt there a plugin that does all that in wordpress admin? something like WPML did - or does, but i havent used it since it wasnt for free anymore.

Comment: another thing - i found that i can edit those mo/po files in django admin with xili-dictionary (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-dictionary/). It seems i finally managed to create correct files for the theme... but the strings i see on the site havent changed.. why?

Answer (score 0):

For my part, [WPML](http://wpml.org/) is the best tool to do this kind of stuff. It's very easy to configure and quite easy to use. There are also a lot of extensions, for example to manage medias, and an extension to buy translations directly from human translators! You should definitively have a look!

Comment: To be more precise, what you try to do can be done with one specific WPML extension called "WPML String Translation" ;)